# how to subset in r for this particular condition?

Tags: r, subset

**df1 and df2 have columns a,b. I want to subset data from df1 such that each entry in df1$a along with df1$b is in  df2$a along with df2$b.**

```
df1
a   b  c
1   m  df1
2   f  df1
3   f  df1
4   m  df1
5   f  df1
6   m  df1

df2
a   b  c
1   m  df2
3   f  df2
4   f  df2
5   m  df2
6   f  df2
7   m  df2
```

desired output

```
df
a   b  c
1   m  df1
3   f  df1
```

*i am using :*

```
df <- subset(df1,(df1$a%in%df2$a & df1$b%in%df2$b))
```

but this is giving results similar to

```
df <-subset(df1,df1$a%in%df2$a)
```

Comment: Probably `df1[(!df1$a %in% df2$a) & (!df1$b %in% df2$b), ]`

Comment: I have changed the question. Please read it again, and this method is also giving the same result as one condition.

Comment: So maybe `df1[(df1$a %in% df2$a) & (df1$b %in% df2$b), ]` then?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, comtaining the outpout you get ant=d the output you expect. Plese see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for how to make an good reproducible example.

Comment: No david, it is yielding result similar to df <-subset(df1,df1$a%in%df2$a).
However i have changed my Question once again, as i am also confused on it. Now it is giving clearer picture of the question.

Comment: You can't just edit the question each time you are getting a working solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am sorry, I am new here. i am still learning how to quote a question. Anyways, lesson learnt. Will try to avoid these silly mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***You can use package `dplyr`:***

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(df1,df2)
#  a b
#1 1 m
#2 3 f
```

**Edit** for the new data.frames with `c` column:
you can use function `semi_join` (also from `dplyr`):

```
semi_join(df1,df2,by=c("a","b"))
#  a b   c
#1 1 m df1
#2 3 f df1
```

***Other option, in `base` R***:
you can paste your `a` and `b` variables to subset your data.frame:

```
df1[paste(df1$a,df1$b) %in% paste(df2$a,df2$b), ]
#  a b
#1 1 m
#3 3 f
```

*and with the new data.frames:*

```
   #   a b   c
   # 1 1 m df1
   # 3 3 f df1
```

Comment: I am not targeting the use of paste as it is increasing the run time. Anyother method ??

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal yes, David's one ;-) or with package `dplyr`, see my edit

Comment: I was turning around intersect base R, but dplyr overload is nice :)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, yes I find `dplyr` `setdiff` and `intersect` functions much better (intuitive...) than `base` R ones for data.frames

Comment: Oooops, looks like i am not good at framing question. One final edit to the question, @CathG can you help ?

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal, that's why it is better to post a reproducible example from the start!... so my `base` R sol is back in the game ;-)

Comment: @CathG Yep, I can use it. Thanks for the input dude, but I am looking for anything other than paste. It is increasing the run time effectively in my original data's case :(

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks, it is indeed not that appropriate ;-)

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal, see my edit, you can go with `semi_join` function from `dplyr`

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do

```
Res <- rbind(df1, df2) 
Res[duplicated(Res), ]
#   a b
# 7 1 m
# 8 3 f
```

---

Edit1: Per the edit, here's a similar `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
Res <- rbind(df1, df2)
setDT(Res)[duplicated(Res, by = c("a", "b"), fromLast = TRUE)]
#    a b   c
# 1: 1 m df1
# 2: 3 f df1
```

---

Edit2: I see that @CathG opened a join battlefront, so here's how we do it with `data.table`

```
setkey(setDT(df1), a, b) ; setkey(setDT(df2), a, b)
df1[df2, nomatch = 0]
#    a b   c i.c
# 1: 1 m df1 df2
# 2: 3 f df1 df2
```